# The Pause button becomes invisible when you click again

Tags: android, exoplayer

I try to implement the following: When I pause, I stop the service and play audio. And when you click on the play button, start the service and play the audio. But the pause button becomes invisible only when you click again. Help me fix it

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String autor;
    private String file;
    private String img;

    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";
    static boolean isPlay = false;
    ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private TextView txtTitle;
    private RoundedImageView imgRadio;

    private ImageButton exo_pause;
    private ImageButton exo_play;

    private String internetStatus = "";

    BroadcastReceiver br;
    BroadcastReceiver serviceReceiver;
    public final static String SERVICE_PARAM = "param";
    public final static int SERVICE_STATUS = 0;
    public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "ru.myapps";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        autor = getIntent().getExtras().getString("autor");
        file = "link";
        img = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img");

        RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayerView(this);
        RadioPlayer.simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        imgRadio = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

        exo_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exo_pause);
        exo_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.exo_play);

        setTitle(title);
        txtRadio.setText(title);


        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);

        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0) {
            startPlayerService();
        }

        exo_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopPlayerService();
                if (exo_pause.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "visible");
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "invisible");
                }
            }
        });

        exo_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(PlayerActivity.this) != 0 ) {
                    startPlayerService();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, file);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_RADIO, title);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = true;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_stop);
        if(exo_play.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            exo_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    private void stopPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = false;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
        if(exo_pause.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            exo_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            exo_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            internetStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        serviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int serviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(SERVICE_PARAM, 0);

                if (serviceStatus == SERVICE_STATUS) {
                    btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(serviceReceiver, filter);

        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (NetworkChangeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver);
        unregisterReceiver(br);
        unregisterReceiver(serviceReceiver);
    }

}
```

I derived logs to know whether the button is visible or not in the listener for exo_pause. The logs show that the button is invisible, but the button is in reality visible and only if you click again on the pause it becomes invisible

Listener `exo_pause.setOnClickListener`

controls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_prev"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_prev"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_rewind"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_fast_forward"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_next"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_next"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.myapps.fairytalesforchildren.activity.PlayerActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/radioInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/player_gradient"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding">

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgRadio"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/radio_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/radio_icon_size"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                ads:riv_border_color="@android:color/white"
                ads:riv_border_width="@dimen/border"
                ads:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/radio_icon_corner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtRadio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="**"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/radioBtns"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#2000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_top"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_bottom">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPLayPause"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/play_btn_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/play_btn_size"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="**"
                android:onClick="onPlayPause"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_play" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/player_gradient"
            ads:show_timeout="0"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your layout xml.

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 0):

delete these lines:

```
if(exo_play.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        exo_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        exo_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

after that, use this lines in your pause button onClickListener and use a method to check that video is playing or not:

```
if(video.isPlaying){
exo_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
stopPlayerService();
}
    else{
 exo_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
startPlayerService();
}
```

I think it helps you.

Comment: I need to make the pause button invisible, and do not change the play button icon